# How is the following derivative equal to the limit on the right side of the equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am puzzled on how the following derivative is equal to the limit on the right side of the equation. I have tried to use the limit definition of a derivative to explain it, but I believe I am making a mistake. An algebraic answer would be the most beneficial, thank you.

$$D_{\vec e_i} f(\vec a) = \left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=0} f(\vec a+s\vec e_i) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\vec a+h\vec e_i)-f(\vec a)}{h}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equality is simply a definition.  This should be assumed to be true.  Now using the definition of a derivative, we can write
$$\frac{d}{ds}f(\vec{a}+s\vec{e}_i)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(\vec{a}+(s+h)\vec{e}_i)-f(\vec{a}+s\vec{e}_i)}{h}. $$
Now just put $s=0$.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much.

Comment: @HoodedMan You're welcome.